# Which one faster either view or sql query?

Tags: sql-server

Which one faster either view or sql query? Please note that both view and sql query having the sql statements.

Answer (score 1):

**They should be equivalent.**

A view is essentially just the result set of a stored query, using all the same indexes and data pages as the underlying tables.

Views can have additional indexes added to speed up operations like aggregates.  [See indexed views.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This question provides good answers already, check it out!

[Query vs. View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324177/query-vs-view)